# How to bring the selected thing in middle in scrollview?

Tags: iphone, scroll

I am developing an application in which what i want is when i select something from scroll

view, the selected thing comes in the middle of the scroll view and one more thing which i

did not mention in question that if i am scrolling the scroll view,how can i fade the

contents  which are not in the middle and again get them back in original color when they are

in middle.

Thanks,

Comment: Without seeing your code we will not able to help you. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are possible solutions to your questions:

- to center, once you get the touch on an object, select it and move scroll view's `contentOffset` according to the selected item's position
- to fade the items, either implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` from the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and watch every item that is off-center, or place semi-transparent (with gradient) images over the edges of the scroll view